# Webdav mapped drive reconnect (Windows)

Tags: password-protection, webdav, remote-connection, net-use

I'm having some problems with a webdav connection that I hope someone can help me out with. I have two options to mount the webdav connection on my PC but both options have flaws.

**Option 1:** Map webdav in File Explorer using the instructions at e.g. https://www2.le.ac.uk/offices/itservices/ithelp/my-computer/files-and-security/work-off-campus/webdav/webdav-on-windows-10.

This works but I can't reconnect! The server requires a password but the mapped drive won't prompt for the password if I use it the next day. I just get an error that it failed to connect.

**Option 2**: Issue a `net use` command from a batch file

```
net use G: <webdav URL> /user:%user% * /persistent:no
```

This does work and does prompt for a password. However, it requires that option 1 be used at least once. And it stops working after a Windows update. Option 1 needs to be used again, then net use works again.

I can handle this for myself but I've got to assist co-workers as well, some of whom are less computer-savvy. So my questions are basically,

1. Is there a way to configure a webdav connection through File Explorer
   (option 1) so that it will always prompt for a password?
2. Is there some way to use net use without going through option 1?
3. Is there some way to make the `net use` command work again after a Windows update without going through option 1?

We're using mostly Windows 10, but a few machines still use Windows 7. Advance thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was solved by starting the `WebClient` service.
Open the start menu and open "**Computer Management**". Choose "**Services**" from "**Services and Applications**". In the List find the "**WebClient**" and activate it by setting the startup type to "**Automatic**" or "**Automatic (Delayed)**"

Alternatively, it can be started by `net start WebClient` but that requires administrator privileges.

PS:
I found a clue hinting to the solution on https://serverfault.com/questions/690231/map-network-drive-to-a-webdav-server-via-powershell

PPS:
I know that this is an ancient topic, but I just spent 2 days in solving this issue...